# Search and Delete first div inside a table in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want to search first div  after `delete` class inside a table. if exist than delete that div.I have sample in 
jsfiddle what I am try.Suggest a correct way to do this.Thanks

[My sample](http://jsfiddle.net/shree/6YpBd/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the sibling `div` element you can use `siblings` method:

```
$(".delete").live("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings('div').remove();
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/6YpBd/2/

Consider using `on` method instead of `live` which is deprecated:

```
$("table").on("click", ".delete", function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

For all jquery versions..

```
$('.delete').delegate('',"click", function() {
    $(this).siblings('div').remove();
});​
```

Comment: You don't use `live`, which is deprecated. Upvote is for you.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO- http://jsfiddle.net/XtN87/

```
$('.delete').live("click", function() {
    $(this).siblings('div').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this demo  http://jsfiddle.net/6YpBd/4/

It just remove the immediate div for the .delete class

If we use siblings() method it removes all the div elements before and after .delete class

```
$('.delete').on("click", function() {
    $(this).next('div').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table tr td').live("click", function() {
$('table tr td > div').remove();
});
```